# Getting values from html elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have this dynamic form where I put every value of the input in an array. The problem is that I'm not able to get all these items in a javascript function.

My html form:

```
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Name 1" id="myInputs[]">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name 2" id="myInputs[]">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name 3" id="myInputs[]">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name 4" id="myInputs[]">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name 5" id="myInputs[]">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name 6" id="myInputs[]">
<button onclick="process()">Next</button>
</form>
```

My script function

```
function process(){
    var name = document.getElementById("myInputs[]").value;
    var name1 = name[0];
}
```

In this function I get the first array entry, but this does only return the first character of the first entry.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "HTML array". What you have is a bunch of elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Id's should always be unique.

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

You should consider using `name="myInputs[]"` instead.

That way you could just do `document.getElementsByName("myInputs[]")` and iterate over the NodeList.

```js
function process() {
  var allInputs = document.getElementsByName("myInputs[]");
  var name1 = allInputs[0].value; // This is the Value of the first Input
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name 1" name="myInputs[]">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name 2" name="myInputs[]">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name 3" name="myInputs[]">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name 4" name="myInputs[]">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name 5" name="myInputs[]">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name 6" name="myInputs[]">
  <button onclick="process()">Next</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS query instead. Note that you should not have multiple items with the same id, they could have the same `name` if you'd like. That's typically used for sending the items to the server as an array and is only recognized by some server processing frameworks

```js
function process(){
  var names = document.querySelectorAll("form [name='myInputs[]']");
  var name1 = names[0].value;
  console.log('First name is' + name1);
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Name 1" name="myInputs[]">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name 2" name="myInputs[]">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name 3" name="myInputs[]">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name 4" name="myInputs[]">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name 5" name="myInputs[]">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name 6" name="myInputs[]">
<button onclick="process()">Next</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the ID should be unique.

Then, the code should be like this:

```js
function process(){
     var name = document.getElementsByClassName("myInputs[]");
     alert(name[0].placeholder);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name 1" class="myInputs[]">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name 2" class="myInputs[]">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name 3" class="myInputs[]">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name 4" class="myInputs[]">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name 5" class="myInputs[]">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name 6" class="myInputs[]">
  <button onclick="process()">Next</button>
</form>
```